# Display the items by iterating over two array-lists in android

Tags: android, android-layout, arraylist, iterator

I have two array-lists and I want to iterate those two lists and I want to display the items of those two lists in four columns as  below.

The two array-lists are say,

```
      ArrayList<BaseItem> highlighted = new ArrayList<BaseItem>();
      ArrayList<BaseItem> normal = new ArrayList<BaseItem>();
```

I have a layout with four columns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/column_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/column_two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/column_three"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/column_four"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

I want to iterate the two arraylists and want to display the items in the following order.

```
  coloumn1      coloumn2   coloumn3  coloumn4

  highlighted1             normal1    normal4

  highlited2               normal2     normal5

  highlighted3             normal3

  highlighted4            highlighted5  

  normal6        normal7   highlighted6
```

Note: Each highlighted item occupies 50% of the screen width and normal item occupies 25% of the screen width.

the above sequence will continue again till all the images get loaded

This is how i am adding the values to the two arraylists

```
    private List<BaseItem> mItems;
   for (Iterator<BaseItem> iterator = mItems.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        BaseItem itemtype = iterator.next();
        if (itemtype.isHighlightPost()) {
            highlighted.add(itemtype);
            System.out.println("This is highlited: " + itemtype);
            Log.i("HIGHLITED",highlighted.toString());
        }
        else{
            normal.add(itemtype);
            System.out.println("This is normal: " + itemtype);
            Log.i("NORMAL",normal.toString());
        }

    }
```

say I have two loops running as folows

```
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items_layout, null);
    int width_post = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.item_width);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_highlight = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params_highlight.width = width_post*2;
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_normal = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params_normal.width = width_post;

for (int j = 0;j<highlighted.size()-1;j++) {  //outer loop for highlighted items
                 BaseItem itemH = highlighted.get(mCurrentItem);
                column1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                column1.setLayoutParams(params_highlight);
                View itemView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
                column1.addView(itemView1);
                column1.setLayoutParams(params_highlight);
                 if(j==4) break;

  for (int k =0;k<normal.size();k++)  {      //Inner loop for normal items
                 BaseItem itemH = highlighted.get(mCurrentItem);
                column3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                column3.setLayoutParams(params_highlight);
                View itemView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
                column3.addView(itemView2);
                column1.setLayoutParams(params_normal);
                 if(k==3) break;

  }

  }

mCurrentItem++;
parentLinearLayout.addView(v);
```

These two above loops are not executing and needs better implementation with correct logic.I know I need to write more loops inside.

Help me in displaying the items as required.Help is always appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your doing or how you're trying to figure which items need to go where. Your loops seem to just place all highlighted items first, and then all normal items. Your layout also doesn't compensate for the larger highlighted items.

My suggestions:

- Your layout should be a GridView with autocollumns set to 2 columns.
- Highlighted items will consume an entire column (half the screen).
- When you need to place normal items, add a second gridview (or grid layout) inside your grid view cells.

Figure out your logic for getting items where they need to be. I have no idea what you're trying to do, but if they can somehow be sorted you can merge the two arraylists and then choose the layout based on whether the item is highlighted or normal.

Comment: ,Thanks for the suggestion,I have tried out with Gridview but it consumes white space at  half of the bottom.so I thought of trying in a different way.I have a  sorted list of both the arraylists.but displaying in that passion is difficult.any idea on displaying the items in a coloumn wise?

Comment: What do you mean about the white space? Perhaps you're not setting the column heights to "wrap_content"?